# Return max index value in vlookup

Tags: excel, max, vlookup

I'm trying to pair a vlookup with a max function.  For some reason it only returns #ref every time I try to use it though.

My sheet looks like this:

```
      A  -  B  -  C  -  D  -  E  -  F  -  G
1...
5 - Prod5  id1  $100  $125  $155  $110  $150
6...
```

A:G is named buyAverages
C:G is named buyAveragesPrices

What I want to do is have a vlookup go and find a value in Col A and then return the highest value in that Col.  So example:

```
      A  -  B
1 - Prod5 *return highest price for Prod5
```

What I wrote in B1, which failed:

```
VLOOKUP(A1,buyAverages,MAX(buyAveragesPrices))
```

So how do I achieve this lookup?  Everything I have found is how to use MAX for the lookup value, but nothing to use max on the returned index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
=MAX(IF(A:A="Prod1",C:G))
```

This is an Array Formula. i.e you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: so if i have a list of prices that regularly get updated do i have to go into each cell and hit ctrl+shift+enter to recalculate every time?

Comment: Nope. the moment `A-G` is updated, the `I` column (in my example) will automatically get updated accordingly.

Comment: so does this not work with named ranges?  it's returning the highest value in the entire range as opposed to the highest value in that specific row.

Comment: No it doesn't return the highest value in the entire range but the  highest value in that specific row. See the above screenshot

Comment: ok, i was missing the if lol, but now that I added the if it just returns a "$ -"

Comment: What is the formula that you are using?

Comment: the formula you gave me.  Here are the values I have; Proteins 2395  $312.52   $259.87   $276.28   $176.69   $365.59; If I use =MAX(IF(A:A="Proteins",C:G)) it returns 0 instead of $260.03

Comment: Did you press ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just pressing enter?

Comment: lol im a dunce, that fixed it sorry, i saw you say that but didn't actually do it.

Comment: One tip though... Instead of working with the entire columns, hardcode it to something lesser (and which you will never reach for example) `=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$1000="Prod1",$C$1:$G$1000))`

Comment: now i just gotta get the next cell to say "where" that max price is at lol (the top row has a list of locations where the prices are from, the cell next to the max value should return which "row" or place that the mex value is listed from)

Comment: Try index/match to find that :)

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one instance of each Product then you can use `INDEX/MATCH` like this

`=MAX(INDEX(C2:G100,MATCH("Prod 1",A2:A100,0),0))`

Longer than Sid's suggestion but doesn't need CSE and might be more efficient if you only have a single match

If you have that formula in Z2, for example, you can use this version to get the location from row 1

`=INDEX(C1:G1,MATCH(Z2,INDEX(C2:G100,MATCH("Prod 1",A2:A100,0),0),0))`

Comment: + 1 The longer the better :p

Comment: As Rory says, it's not the length of the formula, it's what you do with it :)

Comment: Yeah I remember that conversation :) Damn.. it's been a long time :) Howz EE fairing now a days?

Comment: In the XL zone at least - quiet

Answer (score 0):

You can have all in one cell using Vlookup and Max with a nested formula. For example at the top of the page:

```
A1 = Select the name of the product you want to find the max

A2= MAX(BUSCARV($A$1;$A$3:$F$11;3;FALSO);BUSCARV($A$1;$A$3:$F$11;4;FALSO)
;BUSCARV($A$1;$A$3:$F$11;5;FALSO);BUSCARV($A$1;$A$3:$F$11;6;FALSO))
```

It's long but you only have to type it once. With this formula we get all the different amounts in each column and then we ask for the maximum. It works if all the products are different. Change the name of the product and you'll find the MAX in the table.

> Example Prod8
>
> Prod8  41   ;    If we change and you select in   A1 Prod4   you'll
>   get 70  and so on..
>
> Prod1  id1    100 125 155 110
>
> Prod2     50  25  20  75
>
> Prod3     60  65  15  90
>
> Prod4     70  12  50  43
>
> Prod5     100 200 80  25
>
> Prod6     20  28  40  40
>
> Prod7     14  43  60  80
>
> Prod8     22  33  15  41
>
> Prod9     65  48  50  70

Select your range accordingly.

You also could include in A1 a match code to select the name of your products..