# Trying to return topmost row in a lookup

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a sheet that's full of prices, products, and locations.  I currently have a MAX/IF formula that goes to this sheet, finds the product in col A, then returns the highest value from cols C:G.  Now I need to have the next cell over display the location where that price originates.

Example:

```
      A  -  B  -  C  -  D  -  E  -  F  -  G
1 - PRODS - ID - L1  - L2  - L3  - L4  - L5
2...
5 - Prod4  id1  $100  $125  $155  $110  $150
6...

Product: Prod4
Price: $155
Location: ???
```

So here I have a cell that says what product, then the price cell using MAX/IF statements gets to the highest price in col C:G after finding the product in col A.  So how do I now return which location that price is in.  The location box needs to have a formula to return (in this example) "L3" since it's the col that has the highest price.  Row 1 is the headings so it will always have the value needed, but wont always been the same index from the price (because the row the price is in could change).  I've tried making index/match work but can't seem to return an actual value when using it.

**Edit:**
This is a direct copy paste from my spreadsheet.  Buy Averages is the name of the sheet where the products are listed.  G15 is where the highest price is listed, F14 is where the name of the product is listed.  I have several hundred products, but the likelihood of passing 1k isn't very high.

```
=INDEX('Buy Averages'!$C$1:$G$1,MATCH(G15,INDEX('Buy Averages'!$C$2:$G$1000,MATCH(F14,'Buy Averages'!$A$2:$A$1000,0),0),0))
```

Comment: I already answered this in your previous question - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665799/return-max-index-value-in-vlookup/20666036#20666036

Comment: Oh I see it, I didn't notice you post that after I marked the previous question answered by someone else.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: So I put your equation in a cell in the spreadsheet for finding the highest price, and that worked.  But when I put =INDEX(C1:G1,MATCH(Z2,INDEX(C2:G100,MATCH("Prod 1",A2:A100,0),0),0)) where Z2 is your equation for the highest price, I got #N/A in the block where I put that equation.

Comment: So I found where it's breaking down, for some reason if I don't add the sheet to the cells in the current sheet it wasn't working, when I added 'Overview'! (the name of the sheet i was working in) before the cells on the same sheet I was working in it started working.

Comment: Is it working now? If G15 and F14 are in the same cell with the formula you should need to use the sheet name for those

Comment: that's the weird part, it wasn't working until I added the sheet name with it, the only thing I changed was the sheet name and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right lines with Index and Match

first we need to find the max price - you already have that calculated, so I'll just use a placeholder of `MAX(5:5)`

Next, we need to find where that value is by using Match, which gives us `MATCH(MAX(5:5),5:5,0)`, the zero because we require an exact match

Next we use that number in an index, with the first row as where we are searching, a row number of 1, and a column of the number we got from the Match:

```
 =INDEX(1:1,1,MATCH(MAX(5:5),5:5,0))
```

if you are using a version of excel that is 2003 or before, you will have to replace the rows 1:1 with A1:GA1 (or however far the row runs), and the same for the other row references, changing only the row number

```
 =INDEX(A1:GA1,1,MATCH(MAX(A5:GA5),A5:GA5,0))
```

Comment: yeah, I tried this one as well, it's not working either.  @barry-houdini answered it but his answer didn't work either.