# Formula to find the highest number of times accessed in a day for each user in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to work out the maximum number of times a user has accessed the system in a day. There are different dates that they have accessed the system but on some days they have accessed the system more than once and I want to find the day with the highest number.

There are 4 columns: 1. Name (A) 2. Date (B) 3. Total Daily Accesses (C) 4. Highest number of times accessed in a day for each user (D)

I've copied in the formula below which isn't displaying the highest number of times accessed in a day:

**=MAX(C:C,A)**

If anyone could advise where I am going wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to know the user as well or just the total amount of times accessed?

Comment: How do you get the user to run the formula against?

Comment: The ```=MAX(IF(A:A="user_1",C:C))``` but after you type in the formula you have to press control+Shift+Enter else it gives a data type error. I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665799/return-max-index-value-in-vlookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)   Generate a list of unique names using this formula modified to suit your ranges:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))
```

The above formula taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel)

2)   Assuming you generated the list of names in column F and lets assume the range F1:F10

```
=Aggregate(16,6,(A:A=F1)*C:C,1)
```

Copy that down as far as your list of unique names goes.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the names are in column A, the date in column B; one line per user and date, multiple users, possibly multiple dates. For the formulas, let's assume data in rows 2 to 22.

We need an auxiliary column to hold the combination of name and date, like in column E:
`=A2&B2`
for cell E2.
To list the total number of daily logins for each user, put in column C
`=COUNTIF($e$e:$E$22,$A2&$B2)`
Copy this down for each row holding data.

To get the maximum daily events per user, create the list of users in column F (either manually, or using the answer cited in another answer here). Into each line of the list of users, enter
`=MAX(IF(A2=A$2:A$22;C$2:C$22))`
as an array formula (close with Ctrl+Shift+Enter).